# gcc: /home/jamie/aws/btree_int.c|28|error: request for member ‘btree_start’ in something not a structure or union|

Tags: pointers, gcc, struct, malloc

This code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int j_btree_create (int fn_initial_nodes);

typedef struct {
    int depth;
    int value;
    void *item;
    void *left_pointer;
    void *right_pointer;
} j_btree_node_int;

typedef struct {
    int nodes;
    int available_nodes;
    int btree_extension;
} j_btree_descriptor_int;



int j_btree_create (int fn_initial_nodes) {
    int *free_btree_node;
    int loop_counter;
    j_btree_descriptor_int *btree_start;

    btree_start = (j_btree_descriptor_int *) malloc (((sizeof(j_btree_node_int) + sizeof(free_btree_node)) * fn_initial_nodes) + sizeof(j_btree_descriptor_int));
    printf ("btree_start: " . btree_start);
    /* *btree_start.nodes = fn_initial_nodes;
    *btree_start.available_nodes = fn_initial_nodes;
    *btree_start.extension = NULL; */
    for (loop_counter = 0; loop_counter < fn_initial_nodes; loop_counter++) {
        printf ("loop_test:" . loop_counter);
    }
}
```

Produces this error:

/home/jamie/aws/btree_int.c||In function ‘j_btree_create’:|
   /home/jamie/aws/btree_int.c|28|error: request for member ‘btree_start’ in something not a structure or union|
   /home/jamie/aws/btree_int.c|33|error: request for member ‘loop_counter’ in something not a structure or union|
   ||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|

When compiled with CodeBlocks. I have not managed to find an exact answer to my problem (I have looked), does anyone know roughly what I am doing wrong? Probably more than one thing given I am fairly new to C.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf ("btree_start: " . btree_start);
```

This is not how the things are done in `c`. There's no `.` concatenation operator and you do not concatenate strings (pointers to characters) and pointers to structures. If you want to print out the pointer, it's

```
printf("btree_start: %p\n",btree_start);
```

For the loop counter it's

```
printf("loop_test: %d",loop_counter);
```

Comment: PHP developer just got sussed! Thanks Michael.